# When is an alkene formed in a Wurtz reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have read that the Wurtz reaction could take place via either a radical or a nucleophilic substitution reaction. Due to steric hindrance, an alkene would generally be formed on treating a tertiary alkyl halide with Sodium in dry ether. But, what about secondary halides???

For example, what would be the major product(s) of the Wurtz reaction of    2-chlorobutane?

Would we get a mixture of 2-butene and butane, or would we just get 3,4-dimethylhexane(a symmetric alkane)?